# How are these signup forms created in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How are these forms created in ios?
[image]

Is it a tableview with a UILabel and UITextLabel inside each cell with a (UIImageView and UILabel on the picture?

I need to design a form that can be dynamic, I am guessing this may be the way?

Thanks!

Comment: Yep it is - I bet there are some very good open source solutions & libraries out there.

Comment: You already answered your question: In your example you have a UITableView with 1section, 5rows and each row has a UILabel for the text and a UITextField- TextLabel or whatever to enter the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it a tableview with a UILabel and UITextLabel inside each cell with
>   a (UIImageView and UILabel on the picture?

Yes.

Use a `UITableView`. The `UITableViewCell` base class already has some labels you can use. The `textLabel` is used for the bold text on the left. In addition to using that you can set a custom `accessoryView` to be a `UITextField`.

Also some helpful links:

[QuickDialog](http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/open-source-easy-uitableview-replacement-library-great-for-login-screensconfig-screens/) - Open source form library
[Creating Forms](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/uitableview_uitextfield_form.php) - Tutorial explaining how to do it on your own.

Comment: Awesome links! I hadn't thought about setting the custom accessoryView to be a UITextField!Thanks Drummer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like a `UITableView` with the grouped style and some footer text, with labels and an image within the cells.

Answer (score 0):

You must use tabelview style `UITableViewStyleGrouped`

```
UITableView * mytableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```